Итерация по столбцам на каждом листе книги excel
Есть книга эксель, в примере - синтетически единые данные и урезаны по кол-ву листов, в оригинале их 900!
Моя задача: объединить эти листы в одну таблицу
(подставив одну таблицу под другой).
Проблема: данные не одинаковы, и значения некоторых столбцов уехали в столбец без заголовка.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пройтись по листам книги и заменить пропуски в нужном столбце, удалив лишний и затем объединить все таблицы?
вот мой код:
# Загружаем файл в переменную `file`
file = r'C:\Users\julij\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Книга11-копия.xlsx'

# Загружаем spreadsheet в объект pandas
xl_file_obj = pd.ExcelFile(file)

for sheet_name in xl_file_obj.sheet_names:
    data = pd.read_excel(xl_file_obj, sheet_name=sheet_name) # Прочитать листы книги
    for column in data.columns:
        if column == 'Unnamed: 10':
            data['10']=data['10'].fillna('Unnamed: 10')
        elif column == 'Unnamed: 12':
            data['12']=data['12'].fillna('Unnamed: 12')
            break


Как видно, это большой объём данных. А зачем их хранить в рабочей книге Excel? Может, экспортировать в файл в формате CSV?

А что не так с кодом? Лень поотлаживать самому?

Такого рода комментарии совершенно не помогут решить мой вопрос. И да не лень, поотлаживать, на это я потратила уйму времени. Возможно не вижу простых вещей. И обратилась сюда за помощью, а не КРИТИКОЙ (не понятной к чему вообще).

Вы неправильно понимаете, как присваиваются имена неименованным столбцам.
Ваш код ничего не делает.
Я добавила одну строчку...
for sheet_name in xl_file_obj.sheet_names:
    data = pd.read_excel(xl_file_obj, sheet_name=sheet_name) # Прочитать листы книги
    print(f'Sheet: {sheet_name}\nColumns: {data.columns}\n')
    for column in data.columns:
        if column == 'Unnamed: 10':
            data['10']=data['10'].fillna('Unnamed: 10')
        elif column == 'Unnamed: 12':
            data['12']=data['12'].fillna('Unnamed: 12')
            break

... проанализируйте вывод:
Sheet: Sheet1
Columns: Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 'Unnamed: 5', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype='object')

Sheet: Sheet1 (2)
Columns: Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 'Unnamed: 5', 11, 12, 'Unnamed: 8', 13, 14, 15], dtype='object')

Sheet: Sheet1 (3)
Columns: Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 'Unnamed: 5', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype='object')


Спасибо большое, открыла глаза и увидела свою ошибку!)
